# How to return better way in try catch?return emty if there is an error?

Tags: c#

For example:

//Method 1

public static string ABC()
    {

```
  string str= string.Empty;
        try
        {

            return str;
        }
        catch{
            return str;
        }

    }
```

or

```
//Method 2
public static string ABC()
{

  string str= string.Empty;
        try
        {

           str="1234";
        }
        catch{

        }
        return str;
    }
```

Could you tell me better way to return in the above two methods?

Comment: What is your definition of *better*

Comment: It depends on your needs - do you have more details you can share about what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string ABC() 
{
    string str= string.Empty;
    try
    {
        str="1234";
    }
    catch
    {     
        str = "Text if err"
    }
    finally
    {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: return is the best way to return a value from a function. try catch statements are the best way to handle err's along the way

Comment: RadioSpace : I dont's want to cach error in catch and return string emty value if error

Comment: you also don't have to throw an exception you could just swallow the error and return "default" in the catch statement, so what your really looking for is the best way to return a string with a default value if there is an exception

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string ABC()
{

  string str= string.Empty;
        try
        {

           str="1234";
        }
        catch{

        }
        return str;
    }
```

this is the better way